# Button to open Smooch widget

Tags: button, smooch

I want to have a button on my website which will open the Smooch chat window. Is this possible and does anybody have some documentation about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Smooch.open()`](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-web#open) method to cause the messenger to open in response to a button click.

Alternatively, if you don't want the messenger badge to show at all until the user clicks a button, you can delay the call to `Smooch.init()` and only invoke it when the button is pressed, then `Smooch.open()` after

```
Smooch.init({...})
    .then(function() {
        Smooch.open() 
    });
```